# column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Relationships:

```
Item belongs to Product
Product belongs to User
```

Item model scope:

```
  scope :search, ->(search_term) {
    select('products.name, users.*, products.brand, COUNT(products.id)')
    .joins(:product => :user)
    .where('users.name = ? OR products.brand = ?', search_term, search_term)
    .group('products.id')
  }
```

The above results in the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT products.name, users.*, products.brand, COUNT(products.id) FROM "items" 
INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "items"."product_id" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "products"."user_id" 
WHERE (users.name = 'Atsuete Lipstick' OR products.brand = 'Atsuete Lipstick') 
GROUP BY products.id
```

The problem here is that an error occurs:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "users.id" 
must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT products.name, users.*, products.brand, COUNT(product...
```

What could be a fix for this?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

From the error you can see that you should try including `users.id` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
 .group('products.id, users.id')
```

Comment: won't that group records with the same user.id?

Comment: @alexBrand, I have the question as Mr. Obazee.

Comment: Yes, this answer doesn't make sense.  If you group by users.id, that's the same as not grouping.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! I just had to change to this: `.group('products.id', 'users.id')`