# rails query join, order by, group by issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, group-by

Have three models in project

- conversation
- conversation_message
- message

**Conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    #subject
    has_many :conversation_messages, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :messages, :through => :conversation_messages, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "created_at DESC"
end
```

**ConversationMessage.rb**

```
class ConversationMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  #conversation_id, message_id
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :message, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Message.rb

```
#sender_id, receiver_id, message

has_one :conversation_message, :dependent => :destroy
has_one :real_conversation, :through => :conversation_message, :source => "conversation"
```

So I want to retrieve `current_user`'s all conversations and want to show them in order of last message received or sent.
Also want to show single conversation for all of its messages and conversation must ordered by messages included in it.
Using rails 3.0

I tried following query but gives me an error below
query

```
@user_conversations = Conversation
.joins(:messages)
.where(["messages.receiver_id = ?  or messages.sender_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id ])
.group("conversations.id").order("messages.created_at DESC")
```

error

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "messages.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll need to include `messages.created_at` in the `group` clause:

```
@user_conversations = Conversation
.joins(:messages)
.where(["messages.receiver_id = ?  or messages.sender_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id ])
.group("conversations.id, messages.created_at")
.order("messages.created_at DESC")
```

See: [column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297083/column-users-id-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate)

Comment: I want to show single conversation for all of its related messages and conversation list must be ordered by messages into conversation.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid showing multiple conversations by using

`.order("max(messages.created_at) DESC")`

and removing `messages.created_at` from `group` section.

```
@user_conversations = Conversation
.joins(:messages)
.where(["messages.receiver_id = ?  or messages.sender_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id ])
.group("conversations.id")
.order("max(messages.created_at) DESC")
```

It gives you "unique conversations ordered by latest comments".

It's not purely ordering by `messages.created_at` but with changing `max` and `min` and `DESC` and `ASC` will do the job you want, I guess.

Added:
It's been many years since I wrote this answer, and I found out that this does not return the records if there is no messages.
In order to handle that you need to add `NULLS LAST` or `NULLS FIRST` in the query (for postgreql, I don't know for mysql).
ex. `.order("max(messages.created_at) DESC NULLS LAST")`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. The inclusion of `max()` is the difference between this working and not working - and it was breaking my brain for days.